# RequestLogger not intercepting all http requests

Tags: logging, automated-tests, httprequest, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am trying to test this page http://prebid.org/
I want to know that image `http://vcdn.adnxs.com/p/creative-image/27/c0/52/67/27c05267-5a6d-4874-834e-18e218493c32.png` is loaded or not.

Hence i created a logger and checking the count of logger but it does not record this request.

I created custom logger and still it did not log. I am assuming that it only intercepts requests whose initiator is the page itself. So if any request initiated by third party js than it will not be recorded.

Any way i can implement this ?

Comment: Just a quick note: we are looking into this and will let you know as soon as we have any results.

Comment: Thanks @AlexSkorkin I did some debugging and found that testing-hammerhead was not matching for any requests inside dynamically created iframe. It was only happening for Edge and IE. Worked fine in Chrome though

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TestCafe is based on the [testcafe-hammerhead](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-hammerhead) proxy.

All requests go through this proxy, which leads to a delay in loading pages. http://prebid.org/ uses timeouts for "Adserver"/"bids", so at the first load, we see the "All Bidders Took Too Long or No Bid" server response.

Clicking on the "Refresh this ad" button helps to get around this problem, since repeated requests will be much faster.

test-prebid.js:

```js
import { Selector, RequestLogger } from 'testcafe';

const logger     = RequestLogger('http://vcdn.adnxs.com/p/creative-image/27/c0/52/67/27c05267-5a6d-4874-834e-18e218493c32.png');
const refreshBtn = Selector('a').withText('Refresh this ad');

fixture('Prebid')
    .page(`http://prebid.org/`);

test
    .requestHooks(logger)
    (`image loading`, async (t) => {
        await t
            .click(refreshBtn)
            .expect(logger.contains(record => record.response.statusCode === 200)).ok();
    });
```

Test result:

```
> d:\Prebid>testcafe chrome,edge,ie test-prebid.js -e

Using locally installed version of TestCafe.
 Running tests in:
 - Chrome 69.0.3497 / Windows 10.0.0
 - Edge 17.17134.0 / Windows 10.0.0
 - IE 11.0.0 / Windows 10.0.0

 Prebid
 √ image loading

 1 passed (11s)
```

Note: http://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/command-line-interface.html#-e---skip-js-errors

Comment: Hey Thanks, I will definitely try this and let you know.  I placed a console.log in source of testcafe-hammerhead and it was not matching my request. I don't remember the file exactly.